# Facebook API - post on page user 'likes'

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

using facebooks api... how do you post to a page a user likes on that users behalf... for example I have a user that likes a certain page. They can log into my app and make a post on that pages wall via my app instead of logging into facebook to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user grants your app the publish_stream permission then you can post on his behalf on pages he likes (or pages that don't require to like in order to post).

You can try it yourself with the [Graph API Explorer](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer), just go there and click the *Get Access Token* button, then go to *Extended Permissions* tab, select "publish_stream" and confirm.

Then in the address field put a page you like, let's say *southpark/feed* and submit, you should see the feed of that page. Now, change the method to the left of the address field to *POST* and click the *Add Field* link and write in the name "message", enter a value and submit, you should get an id of the post as a result.

Comment: AWESOME IT WORKS! lol i wish i would have stumbled across that tool sooner thanks for the help i got it working now!

Now i just need to get it to work with PAGE_ID/photos/ instead of /feed/

Comment: According to the [docs](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/) you need both publish_stream and manage_pages permissions to post to a page (both to the feed and to the photos) but since we know you don't need the manage_pages for the feed, my guess is that you will be able to do it for the photos as well. The page admins can disable users from uploading photos though, just as they can disable users from posting on the wall.

Comment: right that would be my guess... but when i switch it to /photos/ it doesn't seem to work... oh well i'll keep cracking on it. You've shown me an awesome tool to use. Hopefully this thread helps someone else out... oh and btw when i post to the page it doesn't show up on the wall i have to switch the view to "posts by others"... so maybe thats what the docs are talking about as far as manage_pages... but that doesn't for me as i need people who aren't admins to be able to publish :)